# get value from array with another array index

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm new to php programming, so sorry for any errors whatsoever.

I have a $monthsKeys variable that contains an array going from 0 to 12. 
I have another array ($Months) that contains 12 months from December to January.

I'm trying to create a function that takes the array as parameter and gets the key value from $monthsKeys so that it can return the month's name contained in
$Months.

```
function getnomMois($monthsKeys){
    $monthName= array(['Decembre','Novembre','Octobre','Septembre','Aout','Juillet','Juin','Mai','Avril','Mars','Fevrier','Janvier']);
    foreach($monthsKeys as $monthName){
        $monthName[] = $monthKeys['numMois'];
    }
}
```

What I expect the function to return:

Instead of 12 for the month's number it returns December

What I'm trying to do:

I try to get the key from the $monthsKeys array and use it to get the value from the $MonthName array

What I understand I need to do:

I must extract the key value from the 1rst array and use it to get the value of the 2nd array accordin to the 1rst array key.

ie:
monthKey[12] shoudl allow me to return monthName[12]='December'.

Comment: And what is the problem? Except `array([` syntax.

Comment: `$monthName` on the second line is array, but on the 4th line you change it to `string` (when you loop over the values), and then you are trying to do array operation (`[]`) on that string.

Comment: if you get an element of your `$monthName` array by numbered index; i.e `$monthName[0]`, it will already do what you what it to do. `$monthName[0] = 'Decembre'`

Comment: A few things: 1) Do a simple `print_r($monthName);` right after you declare it and look at the array structure carefully 2) You always want to make sure you don't overwrite your variables, means you don't want to use `$monthName` in your foreach loop if you already used it before to define the array with the months name 3) Take a simple approach and start by writing down in pseudo code what exactly you try to do and then start to write the real code

Comment: What do you expect the function to return? (update the question with the give exact data)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the explanation of your code (and the problem you had):

```
function getnomMois($monthsKeys){
    $monthName= array(['Decembre','Novembre','Octobre','Septembre','Aout','Juillet','Juin','Mai','Avril','Mars','Fevrier','Janvier']);
  //^ here $monthName is array
    foreach($monthsKeys as $monthName){
                         //^ here you change $monthName to string
                         //  becasuse you loop over the arrays and put each value
                         //  inside the $monthName variabl
        $monthName[] = $monthKeys['numMois'];
                //^ here are you tring to do array operation,
                //  but the $monthName variable currently is a string (and you can't do that)
    }
}
```